# Jquery to copy specific data and insert it in a specific blank field in SPS 2013 List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, jquery

Is it possible using JQUERY in SharePoint 2013 Enterprise (On Premise) to copy read only specific data flashing on a SharePoint 2013 List and insert it on a blank field on the same SPS 2013 List?

Comment: What do you mean by specific data flashing?

Comment: Example: there is read only numeric value derived using CSR and its showing below the respective column name, as its read only , therefore I cant use look up to copy the value and what I would think that can do the job to get the value appear on another blank field on the same SPS list is to use JQUERY.

Comment: please check the screenshot - http://imgur.com/1bRXYBq

I want to copy the total=3 from Title and sum=2 from Calc column and paste it onto a new columns, name: Titlecount and Calccount. Reason: Later I want to perform more calculation using calculated column on the value in TitleCount and Calccount. 

Any assistance will be deeply appreciated.